# Unit Test of file upload using MockMvcBuilders with standalone context and SpringBoot 1.2.5

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.5-RELEASE. I have a controller that receive a `MultipartFile` and a `String`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("file-upload")
public class MyRESTController {

  @Autowired
  private AService aService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public void fileUpload(
      @RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) final MultipartFile file,
      @RequestParam(value = "something", required = true) final String something) {
   aService.doSomethingOnDBWith(file, value);
  }
}
```

Now, the service works well. I tested it with PostMan and eveything goes as expected.
Unfortunately, I cannot write a standalone unit test for that code. The current unit test is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest{

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    AService aService;

    @InjectMocks
    MyRESTController controller;

  @Before public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testFileUpload() throws Exception{
        final File file = getFileFromResource(fileName);
        //File is correctly loaded
        final MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("aMultiPartFile.txt", new FileInputStream(file));

        doNothing().when(aService).doSomethingOnDBWith(any(MultipartFile.class), any(String.class));

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/file-upload")
                        .requestAttr("file", multipartFile.getBytes())
                        .requestAttr("something", ":(")
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

Test fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
```

Now, in the `MultipartAutoConfiguration` class from Spring Boot I see that a `MultipartResolver` is auto configured. But, I guess that with the `standaloneSetup` of `MockMvcBuilders` I cannot access this.

I tried several configurations of the unit test that I don't report for brevity. Especially, I also tried rest-assured as shown [here](https://github.com/cosmic-cowboy/spring-boot-multipart-file-upload/blob/master/spring-boot-multipart-file-upload/src/test/java/com/slgerkamp/introductory/spring/boot/multipart/file/upload/application/controller/MultipartControllerTest.java), but honestly this doesn't work because it seems that I cannot mock the `AService` instance.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mixed what [lkrnak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919879/lkrnac) suggested and Mockito `@Spy` functionality. I use REST-Assured to do the call. So, I did as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port:0"})
public class ControllerTest{

    {
      System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "unit-test");
    }


    @Autowired
    @Spy
    AService aService;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    MyRESTController controller;

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;    


  @Before public void setUp(){
    RestAssured.port = port;

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testFileUpload() throws Exception{
        final File file = getFileFromResource(fileName);

        doNothing().when(aService)  
             .doSomethingOnDBWith(any(MultipartFile.class), any(String.class));

        given()
          .multiPart("file", file)
          .multiPart("something", ":(")
          .when().post("/file-upload")
          .then().(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
    }
}
```

the service is defined as

```
@Profile("unit-test")
@Primary
@Service
public class MockAService implements AService {
  //empty methods implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine here unit test (`standaloneSetup(controller).build();`) with Spring integration test (`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`).

Do one or the other.

1. Integration test will need to use something like code below. The problem would be faking of beans. There are ways to fake such bean with `@Primary` annotation and `@Profile` annotation (you create testing bean which will override main production bean). I have some examples of such faking of Spring beans (e.g. [this bean](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/blob/master/05-jms/0500-jms-common/src/main/java/net/lkrnac/book/eiws/chapter05/user/UserService.java) is replaced by [this bean](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/blob/master/05-jms/0500-jms-common/src/main/java/net/lkrnac/book/eiws/chapter05/user/test/TestingUserService.java) in [this test](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/blob/master/05-jms/0500-jms-common/src/main/java/net/lkrnac/book/eiws/chapter05/user/test/CommonJmsUserMessageTest.java)).

   ```
   @Autowired
   private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

   @BeforeMethod
   public void init() {
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
   }
   ```
2. Secodn option is to remove `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and other class level configuration on your test and test controller without Spring Context with standalone setup. That way you can't test validation annotations on your controller, but you can use Spring MVC annotations. Advantage is possibility to fake beans via Mockito (e.g. via InjectMocks and Mock annotations)

Comment: Second option doesn't work: I removed all the annotations to the test class, starting from the one that you mentioned, but the result is: `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?`. Now I try the first approach.

Comment: First approach has some drawbacks. Suppose that I use several services and I want to test several behavior. Then, I have to define in the service defined for the integration-test profile the  options for the different behaviors.

Comment: You original approach wouldn't work at all. No chance. I just namea two approached how you can do MockMvc testing. You have to work it out with one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the request is not a multi-part request. In other words at that point it's expected to have been parsed. However in a MockMvc test there is no actual request. It's just mock request and response. So you'll need to use perform.fileUpload(...) in order to set up a mock file upload request.

Comment: Can you write down a complete example?

Comment: An example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/FileUploadControllerTests.java